# NSMutableDictionary and NSCopying, want to add an object into the key

Tags: objective-c

I am very new to Objective-C and I have come across the NSMutableDictionary. I want to insert an object into the key and from my understanding, you need to make a copy by using the NSCopying class.

I have been reading the Apple's Documentations and I am still puzzled with this. Also I have been searching for examples and I can only seem to find ones that have keys as NSString objects which seems to be automatically copied.

Here is the part of my implementation code:

```
@implementation League
- (void) setPlayerInTeam: (Club*) theClub playerObject: (Person*) person{
    [playerTeam setObject:theClub forKey: person];
}
@end
```

the forKey:person is obviously wrong, how do I make a copy of this by using the NSCopying? Sorry for being a newbie but I am eager to learn.

Many thanks.

Comment: You're getting a bit confused by the documentation.  An object used as a key must support the [NSCopying protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSCopying), which is to say its class must implement `copyWithZone`.

Comment: So do you mean my class League must have the - (id) copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{
    
} ?

Comment: Or in the Person class?

Comment: The class of your `person` variable must support `copyWithZone`.  (And it must actually work.)  And the `isEqual` and `hash` methods must also produce valid results.

Comment: (It's often simpler/more efficient to use a NSString ID of some sort for the key and, if necessary. keep a separate ID-to-person dictionary somewhere else.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see it seems to be much more simpler to do it the NSString id. However, I am just wondering, is there a necessary case to use objects as keys?

Comment: Sometimes you want to use the dictionary to help eliminate duplicates.  Eg, you'd consider to be equal a person with the same name and address.  In such a case the more complex approach is useful.

Comment: Why not just make a `club` property on `Person` and set that to the person's club?

Comment: @AaronBrager - Because the Person might be a member of several Clubs.

Comment: Okay, why not just make a `clubs` property on `Person`?  It could be an array or set of clubs.  Also, if the Person is a member of several Clubs, then the person cannot be used as the key for the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys you use in an NSMutableDictionary have certain restrictions.  NSMutableDictionary copies the key when you use `-setObject:forKey:`.  This means the key must support the NSCopying protocol.  So Person needs to be declared like this:

```
@interface Person : PersonsSuperClass <NSCopying>
```

and it needs to implement the method `-copyWithZone:`  If the Person class is immutable and you are using ARC, `-copyWithZone:` can simply return `self`.

```
-(id) copyWithZone: (NSZone*) zone
{
    return self;  // or return [self retain] if not using ARC.
}
```

If Person is not immutable, `-copyWithZone:` needs to  make a new Person object that is exactly the same as the one you are copying.

```
-(id) copyWithZone: (NSZone*) zone
{
    Person* theCopy = [[[self class] allocWithZone: zone] init];
    // copy all the data from self to theCopy
    return theCopy;
}
```

There are some other things you need to be careful of too.  The method `-isEqual:` must be semantically correct because that is how comparisons are done by NSMutableDictionary.   For example, if a Person is uniquely indexed by a property called userId, you need to make `-isEqual:` use that property to determine if two Person object are equal.  A similar rule exists for `-hash`, two objects that compare equal using `-isEqual:` must have the same hash.

Comment: `[[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init]` is preferable to `[[Person alloc] init]`. Subclasses of `Person` would not get allocated correctly. In addition, zones might be used eventually in iOS so the zone semantics should be used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will read further on the equals and hash.

Comment: @JefferyThomas Good spot.  I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As Hot Licks [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869515/nsmutabledictionary-and-nscopying-want-to-add-an-object-into-the-key/20869964#comment31313311_20869515), you must create a `-[Person copyWithZone:]` method.

```
@interface Person : NSObject <NSCopying>
@property NSString *firstName;
@property NSString *lastName;
…
@end

@implementation
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    Person *copy = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];
    if (copy) {
        copy->_firstName = [self.firstName copyWithZone:zone];
        copy->_lastName = [self.lastName copyWithZone:zone];
        …
    }
    return copy;
}
@end
```

It's a [real pain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907154/best-practice-when-implementing-copywithzone) and full of possible subtle defects. In addition, I would highly recommend creating `-[Person isEqual:]` and `-[Person hash]` methods to avoid other types of defects.

Sometimes it's a must, but avoid it when possible.